# Remove blank page when printing on google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

I use @media print {} to make some changes on print. But when I see the print preview in Google chrome it shows an extra blank page on the bottom. How to remove it ? I try some code for it but it still not working.

```
div:last-child{
    page-break-after: auto !important;
}
body,html{
    height:auto !important;
    min-height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try use this method:

```
* {
  font-size: 1em !important;
  line-height: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: You saved my day.  line-height: 1 !important; works like magic.

Comment: I don't know why this works, but it does.Setting line-height: 1 was the only thing that worked for me. For those who only want to do this while printing, it may be wise to stick this css in the @media print { } directive to avoid messing with other styles.

Answer (score 0):

From my side, it was because bootstrap was adding dummy styles there. I resetted them. See how it adds them.

[image]

So I resetted them:

[image]